# React Hook Form : how to set a field as required when a value of another field is 'TEST'

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

I'm looking for a solution for my issue :
I have two inputs and I want to make  the first one required only when the value of the second input is 'TEST', I'm using React Hook Form with getValues function, [this is my code example](https://codesandbox.io/s/funny-satoshi-fiytvc?file=/src/App.js)

Anyone have an idea how to achieve this please ?
Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

1. As per your implementation, looks like you are trying to make
   'LastName' field is required only if the 'FirstName' field contains the value
   'test'.
2. Initially it was not working because 'requiredFiedl()' function was
   not returning true. I modified it as below and now if the 'First Name'
   the field contains 'test', 'Last Name' will have the required attribute set
   to 'true'.

   const requiredField = () => {
   if (watch("firstName") === "test") return true;
   return false;
   };